# Extract a string from a webpage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webdatagrid

i need to have a label where its text comes from a web page, but for somting it doesnt work out, it appearce to me that the webpae returned null, but the location is correct.

```
    WebBrowser JOJO = new WebBrowser();
string Tesla = "";
                        JOJO.Url = new Uri("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA?p=TSLA");
                        var sal = JOJO.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");// this return null
                        foreach (HtmlElement link in sal)
                        {
    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "D(ib) Mend(20px)")/*this is the class of the element*/        

          {
                            Tesla = link.FirstChild.InnerHtml;
                        }
                    }
                    label11.Text = Tesla;
```

this is the code that i have done so far, can someone see why dosnt work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is null because it didn't load yet when you try to access it. You should be handling it asynchronously.

Handle the [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) event and access the `Document` in the handler.

Replace the code you have with:

```
WebBrowser JOJO = new WebBrowser();
JOJO.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler
                          (this.BrowserDocumentCompleted);
JOJO.Url = new Uri("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA?p=TSLA");
```

And here is the handler:

```
void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
            return;

        string Tesla = "";
        var sal = (sender as WebBrowser).Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in sal)
        {
            if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "D(ib) Mend(20px)")
            {
                Tesla = link.FirstChild.InnerHtml;
            }
        }
        label1.Text = Tesla;
    }
```

Now you will maybe face other problems with redirections. But that is another discussion :)